# Firebase Firestore Bundle problem: db.loadBundle is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to configure bundles as per [Google's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles?authuser=0). Specific error is:

*TypeError: *firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.db.loadBundle is not a function*

Here's my firebase.config.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
var firebaseConfig = {...};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

And my app.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { query, orderBy, limit, collection, getDocs, loadBundle } from "firebase/firestore";

import { db } from './firebase.config.js';
    
import './App.css';

function App() {

...

  const fetchReadings = async () => {

    const readingsArray = [];
    const dailyAveragesArray = [];

    const resp = await fetch('/createBundle');
    console.log("resp: ",resp);
    await db.loadBundle(resp.body);
    const query = await db.namedQuery('all-readings-query');
    const readingSnapshot = await query.get({ source: 'cache' });

    ...
```

Please note that my old `fetchReadings` worked, which had this instead:

```
const readingQuery = query(collection(db, "readings"));
const readingSnapshot = await getDocs(readingQuery);
```

What have I missed here? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`loadBundle()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#loadbundle) is a top level function in the new Modular SDK.

```
import { loadBundle } from "firebase/firestore"

await loadBundle(db, resp.body)
```

The same goes for `namedQuery`. Checkout the linked documentation for reference.